anylogic problem: how to make an agent leave population at reaching a certain block in the flowchart?
I'm simulating a model for a university restaurant and I'm using a population of initial size 4000 people for the students. I want to make the model that who used the restaurant once doesn't use it again.
I want to know how to achieve that?
the population's name is "Agentstudents" and the block's name at which i want the agents to leave upon reaching in the flowchart is "pedsink"
